# Upgrade CPU for IBM xSeries 346 with VT-X?

Tags: central-processing-unit, ibm-xseries

Are there any socket Xeon 603 or 604 CPU's that support VT-X that I can replace the stock one with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Xeon E7300 series](http://ark.intel.com/MySearch.aspx?s=t&VTX=true&FamilyText=Intel%C2%AE%20Xeon%C2%AE%20Processor%207000%20Sequence&ProcessorNumber=E73*) is your only bet.

Answer (score 1):

Both E7300(Tigerton) and E7400(Dunnington) series **won't work** in IBM x346. The VRM delivered with these cpu's won't even fit in the slot and the belonging heathsinks also won't fit since the retention module on the mainboard is different. The only thing that fits are the cpu's itself since the socket is the same but it will overheat with the original x346 heatsinks. Haven't even spoken about FSB differences. If you want cheap VT-x buy IBM 3850 M2 or IBM 3950 M2 with multicore cpu. You're done at EUR150.

Answer (score 0):

Ask Mark states there are no 603 socket chips with VT-X but quite a few 604's - the best you can have being the '[Dunnington](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Xeon_microprocessors#.22Dunnington.22_.2845_nm.29)' series, some of which have 6 cores, so pretty good really. They seem to be available in the UK for around £1000 but you may find them cheaper elsewhere, oh and don't forget to match or come under the TDP budget ok.